# Adding Custom Markdown to Middleman

Tags: ruby, markdown, middleman

**Environment**

Middleman (Latest), Red Carpet MD Renderer

**Problem**

I'd like to make definition lists using custom Markdown

**Background**

I'm new to MD, let alone making a custom parser for it. While I've read several articles, I feel like I'm missing something because they don't seem to work.

**Research**

http://aalvarez.me/blog/posts/custom-markdown-in-middleman.html

Great article, but too specific in examples that don't directly relate to making a definition list.

http://eng.rightscale.com/2015/10/14/custom-markdown-in-middleman.html

Closer, but this seemed overly verbose for something seemingly more simple.

https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet

I've read the docs, but I can't figure out how to apply this to middleman. As the two previous articles mentioned, middleman docs don't really explain how to override the red carpet renderer.

I'm totally open to solutions that exist. I just can't seem to find any!

Thanks